# Logging MacBook firewall is empty

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, firewall

I have enabled the built-in firewall on my MacBook (Sierra v10.12.1), but unfortunately the log files located in /var/log (appfirewall.log and alf.log) stay empty. I contacted Apple Support but they don't know the reason or a solution to this problem. I saw someone with a similar problem and concerns at: [Firewall logging enabled, but not recording](https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7849608) which isn't resolved.

Any ideas how to handle this one?

Comment: Please add your system version by editing your question and adding the proper tag.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in 10.13.4 (High Sierra)

Comment: Same in macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

Answer (score 1):

To get some logging from the `Firewall` you have to define some rules.

Open `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall`, unlock it, and select
`Firewall Options` and add some rules about application you want to block any access from the outside.

Ex. :
[image: Firewall settings]

Once done, lock back the `Security & Privacy` preference menu.

Try any prohibited or allowed access and you will see it appear in `/var/log/appfirewall.log`.